# Php Mysql sum over 2 colums and select from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables.

- Table player

```
P_id = content (1, 2, 3,)

P_name = content (Spieler1name, Spieler2name, Spieler3name)
```

- Table tournament

```
T_id = content (1, 2)

T_date = content (2018, 2019)

T_players = content (123, 123)
```

- Table Games

```
G_id = content (1, 2)

G_tournament_id = content (T_id from table tournament)

G_player_away = Content (as an example user id 1)

G_player_home = content (as an example user id 2)

G_player_away_points = Content (11)

G_player_home_points = Content (8)
```

The Games table has even more data.

Now I want to create a table with PhP as ranking.

Place   name   points

1. Spieler1name   11
2. Spieler2name  8
3. Spieler3name  4
4. ....

Can someone tell me how the php query from the mysql database works? I tested this but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT SUM(G_player_away_points) AS total FROM Games 
UNION
SELECT SUM(G_player_home_points) AS total FROM Games
GROUP BY G_player_away
```

In the code above, he also sums the points from the opponent. This is of course not correct, it should only the points obtained by him appear in the output with php table. Furthermore you have to get the name from the table players. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using single table and multiple column for sum then you should try with this

```
SELECT SUM(G_player_away_points + G_player_home_points) AS total FROM Games 
GROUP BY G_player_away
```

Comment: Also you should be careful for `null` values as if one of `G_player_away_points` or `G_player_home_points` is null, the resulting sum will be null.